# In Excel, how do I replace all instances of text in a cell if any of the text matches values from a range of cells)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

To make things easy for users of this workbook, I've setup column J with data validation (pulling values from Sheet2) that allows for multiple selections of event types (Academic Calendar, Art Exhibits, etc).

I had to use some code to pull that off, but I found a YouTube video that walked me through it so my lack of excel coding experience didn't hold me back.

In order to import this sheet into another program, I can't have "Academic Calendar" as the Event Type, I need it's corresponding code, "et-acacal". The corresponding code is sitting in the next column over on the sheet containing my event types.

Essentially I need to replace every instance of "Academic Calendar" with "et-acacal" and "Art Exhibits" with "et-artgal" as well as the various combinations of event types like "Academic Calendar, Art Exhibits" with "et-acacal, et-artgal"

I've figured out a really crappy way to pull this off, by using multiple SUBSTITUTE functions (see below), but it was tedious to set up and I have to believe there's an easier way to do this. I only had 30ish different event types, what happens if I had/have 100 or 200?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J2,Sheet2!$A$30,Sheet2!$B$30),Sheet2!$A$29,Sheet2!$B$29),Sheet2!$A$28,Sheet2!$B$28),Sheet2!$A$27,Sheet2!$B$27),Sheet2!$A$26,Sheet2!$B$26),Sheet2!$A$25,Sheet2!$B$25),Sheet2!$A$24,Sheet2!$B$24),Sheet2!$A$23,Sheet2!$B$23),Sheet2!$A$22,Sheet2!$B$22),Sheet2!$A$21,Sheet2!$B$21),Sheet2!$A$20,Sheet2!$B$20),Sheet2!$A$19,Sheet2!$B$19),Sheet2!$A$18,Sheet2!$B$18),Sheet2!$A$17,Sheet2!$B$17),Sheet2!$A$16,Sheet2!$B$16),Sheet2!$A$15,Sheet2!$B$15),Sheet2!$A$14,Sheet2!$B$14),Sheet2!$A$13,Sheet2!$B$13),Sheet2!$A$12,Sheet2!$B$12),Sheet2!$A$11,Sheet2!$B$11),Sheet2!$A$10,Sheet2!$B$10),Sheet2!$A$9,Sheet2!$B$9),Sheet2!$A$8,Sheet2!$B$8),Sheet2!$A$7,Sheet2!$B$7),Sheet2!$A$6,Sheet2!$B$6),Sheet2!$A$5,Sheet2!$B$5),Sheet2!$A$4,Sheet2!$B$4),Sheet2!$A$3,Sheet2!$B$3),Sheet2!$A$2,Sheet2!$B$2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage this is using the `VLOOKUP` function. This will look up the relevant event code for a event name in cell J2.

```
=VLOOKUP(J2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$999,2,0)
```

However, you have the added complication of multiple criteria in the same cell. To achieve a VLOOKUP on multiple criteria in the same cell would require you to replace one overly complicated nested `SUBSTITUTE` function with another - given that's why you're asking, I won't go into how that works (lots of unwieldy `IF`s,`MID`s and `SEARCH`es).

Your best bet is to try and reorganise your spreadsheet so you're not trying to get all your criteria into a single cell. Excel isn't really built to do that - the cell is meant to be the most basic unit (hence the name). Try and use multiple columns and do `VLOOKUP`s for each one.